# Data Extension Attribute as a variable

Tags: marketing-cloud

How to declare a data extension field as a variable?
I know there is a option to declare like [First-name] but i have multiple data extension where same name field exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ll need to perform a [Lookup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookup.htm) or [LookUpRows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuprows.htm).

> Returns a rowset from a data extension where the field matches the
>   specified value. Specify additional field value pairs as part of an
>   AND clause. This function returns a maximum of 2000 rows. To better
>   control the number or the order of returned rows, use the
>   `LookupOrderedRows()` function. This limitation enhances script
>   performance.

I urge you to learn the basics of [AMPscript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/index.htm) and the capabilities of Marketing Cloud before you post questions on here. It is generally frowned upon if you do not make an attempt yourself before posting your question